# Click event only displays data after 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at the jQuery.ajax() method to store a piece of JSON data in var d.  I noticed in the console that after the initial button click, the var is stored but it will not display until the 2nd click.  Can someone elaborate on this and propose a solution?

```
    var d;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Weather').click(function () {
            var requestData = $('#City').val() + ',' + $('#Country').val();
            var unit = 'imperial';
            var key = '..........................';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
                method: 'get',
                data: { q: requestData, units: unit, APPID: key },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    d = data.main.temp;
                }
            });
            if (d >= 40) {
                document.getElementById("Text").value = "Value = " + d + " °";
            }
            else if (d < 40) {
                document.getElementById("Text1").value = "Value = " + d + " °";
            }
        });
    });

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter City</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="City" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Country</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Country" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="Weather" >Get d</button>
<input type="text" id="Text" value="T °" />
<input type="text" id="Text1" value="T °" />
```

This is the JSON

```
    "main": {
    "temp": 37.38,
    "pressure": 1030,
    "humidity": 36,
    "temp_min": 35.06,
    "temp_max": 39.2
},
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **if/else** outside the AJAX call, it gets executed immediately after sending the call i.e. `d` is **undefined** then and both conditions fails.

Hence, move **if/else** inside success callback as the value of `d` has been updated by then.

```
$('#Weather').click(function () {
            var requestData = $('#City').val() + ',' + $('#Country').val();
            var unit = 'imperial';
            var key = '..........................';
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
                method: 'get',
                data: { q: requestData, units: unit, APPID: key },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    d = data.main.temp;
                    if (d >= 40) {
                        document.getElementById("Text").value = "Value = " + d + " °";
                     }
                     else if (d < 40) {
                        document.getElementById("Text1").value = "Value = " + d + " °";
                     }
                }
            });

        });
```